# Postgres json_agg Limit

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I'm using json_agg in Postgres like this

```
json_agg((e."name",e."someOtherColum",e."createdAt") order by e."createdAt" DESC )
```

But I want to limit how many rows will be aggregated into JSON. I want to write something like this

```
json_agg((e."name",e."someOtherColum",e."createdAt") order by e."createdAt" DESC  LIMIT 3)
```

Is it possible in some way?

This is full query

```
SELECT e."departmentId",
json_agg((e."name",e."someOtherColum",e."createdAt") order by e."createdAt" DESC ) as "employeeJSON" 
FROM "Employee" e 
GROUP BY e."departmentId"
```

So I want to achieve department with first three employees for each department.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a sub-select that returns only three rows per departmentid and then aggregate the result of that:

```
select "departmentId", 
       json_agg(("name","someOtherColum","createdAt") order by "createdAt" DESC) as "employeeJSON"
FROM (
  SELECT "departmentId",
         "name"
         "someOtherColum",
         "createdAt", 
         row_number() over (partition by "departmentId" order by "createdAt") as rn
  FROM "Employee"
) t
WHERE rn <= 3
GROUP BY "departmentId"
```

---

<sup>Note that using quoted identifiers is in general not such a good idea. In the long run it's more trouble than they are worth it.</sup>